# IS warning about string ID "IDS_ERROR_27555" not being found in string table

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010, installshield-2012

I have an Installshield2010 project that has had this warning since before my employment

`ISDEV : warning -3028: The string ID "IDS_ERROR_27555" was not found in the string table. It is referenced in the table:"Error" in column:"Message".`

Looking in the svn history, this row was added to Error table a few years ago - alongside a seemingly unrelated change

`<row><td>27555</td><td>##IDS_ERROR_27555##</td></row>`

However as the error indicates, there is no corresponding entry in the ISString table.
I'm curious how it got added.   The IDS_ERROR strings look like canned strings, it seems really unlikely the person who added this to my ism did so manually.

Of course Flexera's forums [are a ghost town](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?p=465389).  I did find an [ism that has that string defined](http://code.google.com/p/google-saml-bridge-for-windows/source/browse/tags/2.0/SAML_MSI_2.0/GSARKS_x64/Google+Services+for+Sharepoint.ism?r=130#3534) as
`<row><td>IDS_ERROR_27555</td><td>1033</td><td>Error attempting to apply permissions to object '[2]'. System error: [3] ([4])</td><td>0</td><td/><td>1394414478</td></row>`

Do any of your ism's have IDS_ERROR_27555 defined or referenced? Am very sure I can delete the string and be no worse for wear... but it bugs me to not know what happened.

Comment: As an aside, Flexera Software's forurms are at community.flexerasoftware.com; InstallSite is not run by them.

Comment: opps! I copy/paste failed and got the wrong link in there. editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember in which version we added these strings, but you can get them by importing the strings file for your language (1033.txt for English) under the Languages folder. Upgrading across versions of InstallShield should have added this string. You can add them yourself by importing the strings file in the String Editor view. Of course if you've modified other strings, you'll want to ensure that you keep your preferred version.

Comment: You're correct - the string is indeed defined in 1033.txt on my machine, I'm pretty sure the ism has been through several Installshield upgrades using many installshield installs... something odd must have happened long ago.  I've added the string and all is well